# Equivalent characterization of compact operator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T: X \to Y$ be an operator between two normed vector spaces. Recall that $T$ is said to be a compact operator whenever $T$ maps the closed unit ball $U$ of $X$ onto a norm relatively compact subset of $Y$. In case $Y$ is Banach space, $T$ is compact if and only if $T(U)$ is a norm totally bounded subset of $Y$. In there, ı need help to prove that if $T(U)$ is a norm totally bounded subset of $Y$ then $T$ is compact. I've proved the other side. How can ı extend a totally bounded set to a compact set under which conditions?

Comment: $(X, d)$ is compact $\iff$
$(X, d)$ it is complete and totally bounded

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format your posts using MathJax (not too bad; mostly enclosing math symbols in dollar signs, $, and using \to or some such for arrows).